# Uploading files according to the selected type?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have listed file types (excel, csv) using q-select with vue. I want to filter the files accepted for upload (:accept="selectedFileType") using q-uploader by the file type that the user selects from this list. For example, when I select excel from the q-select, that is, the dropdown menu, only the excel files on the local computer will be displayed on the dialog screen for the upload.

```
<template>
  <q-select v-model="selectedType" :options="types" />
  <q-uploader :accept="selectedType" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedType: null,
      types: [
        {
          label: 'Excel Files',
          value: '.xls, .xlsx'
        },
        {
          label: 'CSV Files',
          value: '.csv'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The sample code I added does not work as I want.

```
 <q-uploader :accept="selectedType == csv ? '.csv' : '.xls .xlsx'"/>
```

When I do this, only excel files are listed on the dialog screen.[image]

Comment: What is the problem with the example you shared? Please be more specific. Also it is recommended to include a snippet in order to make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: For example, when I select excel from the q-select, that is, the dropdown menu, only the excel files on the local computer will be displayed on the dialog screen for the upload. @guyaloni

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet? (See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) for more info)

Comment: no need, I solved the problem anyway, for your attention. Thanks. I found the solution by adding emit-value and map-options props to q-uploader. @guyaloni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding emit-value and map-options props to q-uploader.

`<q-uploader :accept="selectedType" emit-value map-options />`